# Timing into javascript loop with passing parms

Tags: javascript, html, function, settimeout, timing

Can anyone give me an advice how to time this function:
I'm trying to execute:

```
GameBaccarat.prototype.playHands = function(requests) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (game.instance.players[i]) {
            var hand = i;
            game.instance.hand = i;
            this.activeHands += 1;
            var request = requests[i];
            connector.sendRequest(request, function() {
                var xhr = this;
                game.instance.handleDealResult(hand, xhr)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

like:

```
setTimeout(function(){connector.sendRequest(request, function() {var xhr = this; game.instance.handleDealResult(hand, xhr) });}, i*200);
```

but so far havent succeded.. Please help :)

P.S.
I tried passing, var that = this, and add it to timeout, dosent work :(

Tried:

```
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function(){
                connector.sendRequest(request, function() {
                var xhr = that; 
                game.instance.handleDealResult(hand, xhr) });
                }, i*200, that);
```

Did not work, just crashed the callback :(

Comment: If you would describe in words what your objective is, I'm sure someone can help you.  But just giving us code without telling us what you're trying to accomplish isn't enough for us to know how to help.

Comment: I'm trying to set gaps between sending Requests, right now if i send 3 requests and aftwerwards work work with them, they sometimes get mixed up in order:
thats why I'm trying to do like:
send a request every x secconds, so there is a time gap between so responses dont change order as they where requested.

Comment: it is because of the this param, im posting an answer right now

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sequence the multiple requests, you can do them like this where you start the next request only when the previous one is complete and you keep a counter for how many you've done:

```
GameBaccarat.prototype.playHands = function(requests) {
    var requestCntr = 0, numRequests = 3;
    var xhr = this;
    function next() {
        if (requestCntr < numRequests && game.instance.players[requestCntr]) {
            game.instance.hand = requestCntr;
            xhr.activeHands += 1;
            connector.sendRequest(requests[requestCntr], function() {
                game.instance.handleDealResult(requestCntr, xhr);
                ++requestCntr;
                next();
            }
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

If you want to sequence and add a delay between requests, you can add a `setTimeout()` delay to starting the next request:

```
GameBaccarat.prototype.playHands = function(requests) {
    var requestCntr = 0, numRequests = 3;
    var xhr = this;
    function next() {
        if (requestCntr < numRequests && game.instance.players[requestCntr]) {
            game.instance.hand = requestCntr;
            xhr.activeHands += 1;
            connector.sendRequest(requests[requestCntr], function() {
                game.instance.handleDealResult(requestCntr, xhr);
                ++requestCntr;
                // 1 second delay before next requeset
                setTimeout(next, 1000);    
            }
        }
    }
    next();
}
```